# How to remove noise from an image using pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tesseract, noise-reduction

I am trying to de-noise an image that I've made in order to read the numbers on it using Tesseract.
[Noisy image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRepB.png)
Is there any way to do so?
I am kind of new to image manipulation.

Comment: It would be better if you can provided original /not binarized image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from PIL import ImageFilter

im1 = im.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)

im2 = im.filter(ImageFilter.MinFilter(3))
im3 = im.filter(ImageFilter.MinFilter)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

You have to read Python pillow Documentation

Python pillow Documentation link:
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Pillow image module:
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFilter.html#module-PIL.ImageFilter

How do you remove noise from an image in Python?
The mean filter is used to blur an image in order to remove noise. It involves determining the mean of the pixel values within a n x n kernel. The pixel intensity of the center element is then replaced by the mean. This eliminates some of the noise in the image and smooths the edges of the image.

Comment: Yes, filtering an image using a mean, median or gaussian for example will denoise it. Different filters have different capabilities (like edge preservation). That being said you probably should apply the filter before "thresholding" the image. So filter the grayscale image and then convert to black and white.

Comment: It shows the same result, the numbers are clear, but the background is really messy.

Comment: The documentation link is broken. This link should be used instead: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFilter.html#module-PIL.ImageFilter

Comment: PIL does not offer any such "mean" filter. It offers a median and a mode filter. Of those, the [`MedianFilter`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFilter.html#PIL.ImageFilter.MedianFilter) probably best resembles the given description.

Answer (score 1):

The Pillow library provides the [`ImageFilter`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFilter.html#module-PIL.ImageFilter) module that can be used to enhance images. Per the documentation:

> The ImageFilter module contains definitions for a pre-defined set of filters, which can be be used with the [`Image.filter()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.filter) method.

These filters work by passing a window or kernel over the image, and computing some function of the pixels in that box to modify the pixels (usually the central pixel)

The [`MedianFilter`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFilter.html#PIL.ImageFilter.MedianFilter) seems to be widely used and resembles the description given in nishthaneeraj's answer.